# Linkedin API details for notification in your application if user has updated his/her profile

Tags: linkedin-api

I am looking for help for Linkedin api to get the notification in my system if user has updated his/her profile. I am able to get the user data if user is login using linkedin in my system but i am more interested to know by notification if user made any changes.